# TypeError: Cannot read property 'MS_APP_CLIENT_ID' of undefined

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper

I tryed to use the code provided by the https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol, but the browser shows "TypeError: Cannot read property 'MS_APP_CLIENT_ID' of undefined" in the console, and the chat does not show up.

The most strage thing is that i had the same code working few days ago. So the problem might be in the https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js

Documentation: https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol

Code to replicate the issue
Beforre anyone asks, i've set the Microsoft App ID in the data-bot-id

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="skype-button bubble " data-bot-id='YOUR_BOT_ID'></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]